# How to make equal size column width of two tables

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

This is the table header:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/roster_bat_stats_table_header_adv1"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@drawable/divider_stand_table_list"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:stretchColumns="9"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@id/header_table_row"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="BAT"
                        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_weight="0.0652"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                    etc...
```

Here is the actual table without header:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollBatStatsAdv1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/rosterBatStatsTableAdv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@drawable/divider_stand_table_list"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:stretchColumns="9"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </TableLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I'm adding `android:layout_weight="0.0652"` in the header section above. 
The actual table rows are added programmaticaly by creating TableRow and setting weights for each element inside of it:

```
double[] weigths   = new double[]{0.0893, 0.0893, 0.2500, 0.0833, 0.1012, 0.0952, 0.0893, 0.1071, 0.0952};
```

creating table row:

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tableRow.setOrientation(TableRow.HORIZONTAL);
    tableRow.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(trainingPlayerSelectRowColor));
    tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tableRow.setTag(player.getId());
```

Creating elements inside of tablerow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; ++i) {
        TextView h1 = new TextView(context);
        h1.setText(values[i]);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) weights[i]);
        h1.setLayoutParams(params);
        h1.setTextColor(resources.getColor(standingsTableHeadTXT));
        if (i == 2) {
            h1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        } else {
            h1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
        h1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        tableRow.addView(h1);
    }
```

The `values` array is an array of Strings.

I made weights (layout_weight) in the `header_table_row` same as the rows added programatically in the actual table. But they do not match:

[image]

Is there any mistake or how can I make columns in both tables match?

Comment: Just a comment to test things out first, can you make sure setting up `0dp` in the width when you have a weight doesn't fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just populate header programmaticaly than? Additionally you will have everything connected with populating the table in one place. It won't be a huge overhead also.

Comment: @muminers worked!

Comment: Nice, happy to help!